# npm ci does not respect workspace flag provided using -w or --workspace

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-workspaces, pnpm-workspace, npm-ci

installing a project with multiple `workspaces` (workspace-x, workspace-y, workspace-z) using `npm ci -w workspace-x` command results in below error

```
`npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
```

The dependent module versions in the `package-lock.json` and `package.json` for `workspace-y` and `workspace-z` but not for `workspace-x`. Hence it's expected to run `npm ci` for the workspace-x

Although this is not working as expected with `-w` or `--workspace` flags, it works when removed workspace-y and workspace-z    from the package-lock.json workspaces field.

Any workarounds or suggestions to run `npm ci` only for workspace-x, where other workspaces are not eligible for `npm ci`?